# WP8.1 String Resource in ResourceDictionary

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

How do I define a string in a ResourceDictionary in my WP8.1 app?

I already added

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

to my ResourceDictionary but Visual Studio 2013 says that "sys:String" wasn't found.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably becouse you are targetting WP8.1 *Runtime* app. As method you have described will still be working in WP8.1 *Silverlight*, in *Runtime* you can declare build-in types in xaml like this:

```xml
<x:String x:Key="myKey">Text</x:String>
```

More about differences and porting *Silverlight* app to *Runtime* you will find [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn762319.aspx).